# 7-Zip error while installing printer driver: "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: drivers, printer

I cannot install the HP Deskjet F2480 driver due to this error.  The driver was downloaded from HP's website and is for Windows XP 32-bit.  How do I fix this?  I did some research and I found that this is caused by the registry.

Specifications:

- Windows XP SP3
- 1GB RAM
- 500GB hard drive

Comment: I've edited the question for you, but please try to write your questions more clearly next time so that we can easily understand your problem.